# Detect complete data received on 'data' Event in Net module of Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

Currently when we send a large data over TCP *data* event will receive it in chunks. Is there a way where we able to detect that all data is received and return complete data.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently when we send a large data over TCP data event will receive it in chunks. Is there a way where we able to detect that all data is received and return complete data.

TCP is just a continuous stream of data.  There's no start or end to a given transmission at the TCP level unless you close the connection and use a closed connection as a signal that the data finished.

So, if you want to know where a given chunk of data starts and stops, you need to design a way within the data you send in order to know that (essentially build your own little mini wire format or protocol).  There are a zillion different ways to do that and that's one of the reason we have so many different protocols built on top of TCP.  The two simplest schemes are to:

1. **Send a length of your packet** and then send that many bytes.  The recipient then reads the length and knows when it then reads that many bytes, it has the whole chunk.
2. **Use some sort of delimiter** that won't appear in the actual data.  For example, some simple protocols use a linefeed as a delimiter.  You send a bunch of text and then terminate it with a linefeed.  The receipient reads data until they get a linefeed and that tells them they have a complete chunk of the data. There are many possible delimiters depending upon what the type of data is.

Other protocols such as webSocket or socket.io have message-based paradigms built into them doing this work for you.  You send a message at one end and then receive a whole message at the other end.

Some options are more or less appropriate based on the type of data (text/binary) you're sending and the length of the data and what the character of the data is (whether there are possible delimiters that won't be in the actual data).